# Assigning default images to a channel

Tags: image

As part of redesigning our site, we want to make sure that every entry for a specific channel is displayed with an image. All the content posted does not have good specific images associated with them, so I am looking for a good way to assign a pool of default images to the channel. Then, if an entry does not have a specific image associated with it, it would instead be displayed with a random image from the default set.

Is this doable? I am on EE 5.x.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, off-course it is doable. For this you need to create **Template Variable** for storing the placeholder image. You just need to call this placeholder image when there is no image in file field.

You should try code in below manner.

```
{if file_field_name}
    {!-- Image field name associated with channel --}
{if:else}
    {!-- Placeholder Image (variable_name) --}
{/if}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, haven't made much use of template variables, so it didn't occur to me. Looks like a very elegant solution!